# Why in this JUnit test it shows wrong number?

Tags: java, junit

So here is my solution code:

```
public int count_two_char(String s, char c, char d){
    int count = 0;
    int count1 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
            count = count + 1;
        }

        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < s.length(); i1++) {
            if (s.charAt(i1) == d) {
                count1 = count1 + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return count + count1;
}
```

And here is my test code:

```
@Test
public void tests3() {
    code.Solution s =  new code.Solution();
    String input = "llss";
    int expected = 4;
    char c ='l';
    char d ='s';
    int actual = s.count_two_char(input, c, d);
    assertTrue("Expected was" +expected+"but the actual was" +actual  ,  expected == actual);
}
```

But when I test it. It shows a error which is expected was 4 but the actual was 10. why?? I'm so confuse right now.

Comment: You can use `assertEquals (expected, actual)`. In case of failure it will display automatically a message that is similar to yours, without the need to write it yourself.

Comment: Your loops are nested, when in fact it looks like you want two separate loops. I'd suggest eliminating one of the loops altogether and just compare each character as you encounter it, once. As it were, it looks like your unit test functioned properly, because it caught incorrect behavior in your function. Well played.

Answer (score 7):

Because your braces aren't indented well, it appears that you have 2 separate `for` loops.  But after lining them up better:

```
  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++){
     if(s.charAt(i) == c){
        count = count + 1;
     }


     for(int i1=0; i1<s.length(); i1++){
        if(s.charAt(i1) == d){
           count1 = count1 + 1;

        }

     }

  }
```

You can see that the second `for` loop is nested inside the first `for` loop, so your `count1` will be higher than expected.

Move that last brace between the `for` loops and they will be unnested.  That should reduce the count returned so that your test passes.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have a `for` loop that you do not need. Both `if`s should go into the same loop, like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (s.charAt(i) == c) {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    if (s.charAt(i) == d) {
        count1 = count1 + 1;
    }
}
```

As it stands, the number of `d` characters is multiplied by the length of the string, producing 2+4*2=10.

You can make your code more idiomatic to the language if you replace `count = count+1` with the equivalent `count++`. You could also drop `count1` altogether, because you add the two counts at the end anyway.

Comment: Where would `i1` come from?

Comment: And why should he still use `count1`? :D Just always increment `count` instead.

Comment: @Tom I think it's OK to keep two counts, In case he wants to see the results in the debugger, or log them for tracing purposes. But you're right, one `count` is perfectly sufficient here.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight In this case you're right. Since he might be new to programming he might want to log/trace these two variables. And a proficient programmer would refactor that method anyway (also to avoid two dedicated counting variables) :D.

Comment: @Tom You're right, professional programmers would probably do it differently. For example, they would not limit it to `count_two_chars`, making it `countChars(String s, char... chars)`, letting their callers pass as many `char`s as they wish.